# calculate straight line declining

Tags: javascript, accounting

i have asset (say vehicle) with value of 1000 in this year...

```
var assetCurrentBookValue = 1000
```

vehicle will depreciate within 5 years... that means the value will become 0 in the next 5 years...

```
var assetLife = 5
```

yearly depreciation become...

```
var assetYearlyDepreciation = assetCurrentBookValue / assetLife
```

i need to calculate yearly value after yearly depreciation like so...

```
year    assetYearlyDepreciation         assetBookVaue
2016    200                                     1000
2017    200                                     800
2018    200                                     600
2019    200                                     400
2020    200                                     200
2021    200                                     0
```

i need to convert into array like so...

```
[
    [2016,1000],
    [2017,800],
    [2018,600],
    [2019,400],
    [2020,200],
    [2021,0]
]
```

here my workaround...

```
var index = Array.from(Array(assetLife).keys());
var thisYear = new Date().getFullYear()

var assetYearlyBookValue = [[thisYear,assetCurrentBookValue]]

index.forEach((o) => {
    assetYearlyBookValue.push([o + thisYear + 1, assetCurrentBookValue - assetYearlyDepreciation])
});
```

but ive got..

```
[
    [2016,1000],
    [2017,800],
    [2018,800],
    [2019,800],
    [2020,800],
    [2021,800]
]
```

any help would be appreciated... thank Youu..

Comment: It is really not clear what you are trying to do with this code. What is `assetEconomicLife`?

Comment: typo.. should be `assetLife`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your results from `assetCurrentBookValue - assetYearlyDepreciation` and `new Date().getFullYear()` and store them into variables so that you can get a continuously changing result:

```
var index = Array.from(Array(assetEconomicLife).keys());
var thisYear = new Date().getFullYear()

var assetYearlyBookValue = [[thisYear,assetCurrentBookValue]]
var lastRes = assetCurrentBookValue

index.forEach((o) => {
    lastRes -= assetYearlyDepreciation
    assetYearlyBookValue.push([o + (++thisYear), lastRes])
});
```